# How do I get readable javascript files in the 'development' mode of webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

How do I get readable javascript files in the 'development' mode of webpack?

[This column](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-mode-and-optimization-5423a6bc597a) describes how webpack 4 (and now 5) have modes: development and production.

By default, a development mode javascript file has this at the top:

```
/*
 * ATTENTION: The "eval" devtool has been used (maybe by default in mode: "development").
 * This devtool is neither made for production nor for readable output files.
 * It uses "eval()" calls to create a separate source file in the browser devtools.
 * If you are trying to read the output file, select a different devtool (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)
 * or disable the default devtool with "devtool: false".
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ describes devtool in great detail, but doesn't say concretely how to set it, or how to set it conditionally on mode.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/ shows devtool in context in a config file, but doesn't say how to set it conditionally on mode.

What is a simple webpack 5 config file snippet that shows devtool set to a value only in development mode that will let me see and debug my javascript in the chrome debugger (or some other reasonable environment)?

**EDIT**: In my `package.json` for `npm` I have build targets for prod and development:

```
  "build-dev": "webpack --mode development",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
```

So I'm running `webpack --mode development`.  I want my webpack config to have readable javascript files, but only for the development mode.

Comment: If you run pakage.json it is best to add `webpack --mode=development` but you can also add an entry in the configuration file itself `module.exports = { mode: 'development', };` For this you need one more entry `devtool: 'eval-source-map', ` which generates the source map. Here's my [webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/config/webpack.dev.js#L24)

Comment: Thanks. I'm running `webpack --mode development`. When I do that, it does not have readable javascript (as noted above). However, I want my webpack config to have readable javascript files, but only for the development mode.

Comment: Then add `devtool: false` to your config as well, as stated in the comment (or use any of the other values that produce the output you want).

Comment: And will adding `devtool: false` affect the production build? I guess I can just try it, but it seemed to me like it would, which is why I didn't try it.

Comment: It shouldn't but you can easily verify that by creating a production build.

Comment: Although it doesn't directly answer your questions, this might be useful: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/source-map

Comment: And of course you can also change the value of `devtool` only for development mode: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

Comment: "And of course you can also change the value of devtool only for development mode". I don't know how to do that. That's literally the question I asked. Also, I visited the link you sent, but I don't know enough about webpack config to understand that syntax, whether the "devtool =>" with mode development means change it only for development.

Comment: But I think the answer will be that the `devtool` setting only affects the development build.

Comment: *"I don't know how to do that."* See the last code example at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

Comment: My example consists of three separate files. The link you provided at the end of the page is an example of how this is done in one file. Ie. that you check whether it is a production or development version and on the basis of that you can enable or disable individual configuration elements. `devtool: argv.mode === 'development' ? 'eval-source-map' : 'none',`

Comment: As for `devtools` it adds sourcemaps, this is needed for development. For example, we have an error in the code, we do not rummage in the wbpack files, but by clicking on devtools in chrome and clicking on the error, it takes us to the file and to a specific line with the error which is our original input file.